# Create a function that contains only the first occurrence of a letter from the original phrase

Tags: python, string, loops, iteration

The function needs to behave as follow: [image]

The first letter occurrence can be upper or lower case (newPhrase).
Non-alpha characters - are left unchanged.

So far I thought of :

```
def keepFirstLetter(phrase):
'''Returns a new string that contains only the first occurrence of a 
letter from the original phrase. 

    letterSeenSoFar = ''
    newPhrase = ''
    if (letterSeenSoFar == '' or letterSeenSoFar[-1] != letterSeenSoFar):
         letterSeenSoFar += c
    for letter in letterSeenSoFar:
        if letter.isalpha:
            newPhrase += char
        else:
            newPhrase += letter
    return newPhrase
```

Comment: Looks okay so far... what's the problem?

Comment: When I test it, for example keepFirstLetter(Amy says, me?) it returns me again Amy says, me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name was in the question so let me take a try.
I learned set.add() from James for the first time. (Thank you, James.) James' code is shorter and runs faster (3.48us vs. 3.76us on my PC).

```
def keepFirstLetter(phrase):
    phrase = list(phrase)
    '''Returns a new string that contains only the first occurrence of a 
    letter from the original phrase.'''
    letterSeenSoFar = []
    newPhrase = ''
    for char in phrase:
        # if char is not an alphabet, add char to the newPhrase as is
        if not char.isalpha():
            newPhrase += char
        # if char is an alphabet and not seen so far, add char to the newPhrase and append it to letterSeenSoFar
        elif char.lower() not in letterSeenSoFar:
            letterSeenSoFar.append(char.lower())
            newPhrase += char
    return newPhrase

print(keepFirstLetter('Amy says, " Me?"'))
```

This outputs:

```
Amy s, " e?"
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution it made the problem very clear for me. Now I understand where I was wrong. (I'm going to start using your name as test more times )

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be on the right track.  If you want to improve you efficiency, you can store the seen letters as a set.  Searching a set is O(1).

```
def unique_first(s):
    letters = set()
    out = ''
    for x in s:
        if not x.isalpha():
            out += x
            continue
        if not x.lower() in letters:
            out += x
            letters.add(x.lower())
    return out
```

Comment: I did not cover sets in class yet so I cannot use it. Is any other way to do it? (adding to the string)

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward, sure-to-have-learned solution is probably:

```
def keepFirstLetter(phrase):
    output = ''
    for letter in phrase:
        if (letter.lower() not in output.lower()) or (not letter.isalpha()):
            output += letter

    return output

print(keepFirstLetter('Amy says, "Me?"'))       #  Amy s, "e?"
```

(the parens around the two if clauses are optional)

James's solution still gets my vote though.

Comment: Thank you, I loved to see the different ways the problem can be solved!